# PHP - Code is create individual tables for each record from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to create one table that will loop through all the records from my database but it seems to be create individual tables for each record instead.

```
$query = 'select * from images';
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


for($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++){
$row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
echo '<header><h1 class="gallerytitle">Photo Gallery</h1></header>';


foreach($row as $next) {
{
  echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Imageid</th>
<th>Image name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th>Caption</th>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $next['imageid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $next['imagename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $next['description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><img src='".$next['image']."' width='20%' height='auto'></td>";
echo "<td>" . $next['caption'] . "</td>";
echo "<td> <a class='readmore' href='delete_confirm.php?imageid={$next['imageid']}'>Delete</a></td>";
echo "<td> <a class='readmore' href='update_form.php?imageid={$next['imageid']}'>Update</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
    echo '</section>';
}
```

Comment: you are creating a new table on each round-trip of your foreach... put `echo "<table border='1'>` and the headers outside the foreach loop.

Comment: You need to move the `<table border="1">...</th></tr>` out of the `foreach` loop

Comment: Okay thank you that fixed it but there is another issue, only one record is in the table and the other records are not inside the table.

Comment: Update; Ok, I've just found a typo in the foreach brackets as I had two of them for some reason. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would loop around the `tr`

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Imageid</th>
<th>Image name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th>Caption</th>
</tr>";


foreach($row as $next) {
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $next['imageid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $next['imagename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $next['description'] . "</td>";
    // all the other columns 
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```